# Expandable table view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is it possible to make an expandable table in Android, that is similar to the expandable list view, but where the child items are in a table/grid format.
For example, something like is here: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/
, but with the child items being a grid of images.

This is how far I've gotten so far (in activity_main.xml using Eclipse Kepler) and am stuck on:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ExpandableListView>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ExpandableListView>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your expandable list view with usage of [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) you can make your child cells to be `TableViews` or GridViews or whatever you want inside.

Just inflate view which you want in:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_with_grid, null);
    }

    // get your views from convert view here

    return convertView;
}
```

Here you got ExpandableListAdapter [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: Your answer is no doubt correct, but I'm afraid I'm very new to programming (probably too new to even be trying this). Please could you explain a bit more for me to better understand how to accomplish what you mean. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks, am working on it. It's a bit complicated because I'm putting the tableview in the expandablelistview in a tabview with swipe... so am trying to learn my way through it.